# use LWP::Simple to get ftp site content in Perl

Tags: perl

I am having some issue here using LWP::Simple to get ftp site content in Perl. It would work fine if the site used http, but not ftp, for example ftp://ftp.di.uminho.pt/pub/ctan/fonts/. But in my firefox browser, I can view the content as html.

So how to get the html of the site in this case?

Comment: Your firefox browser 'talks' FTP and displays the 'page' to you as if it were an HTML page, but it isn't :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LWP returns a document of the type `text/ftp-dir-listing` for a FTP directory. Use [File::Listing](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aListing) to parse it.

```
$ GET -USe ftp://ftp.di.uminho.pt/pub/ctan/fonts/
GET ftp://ftp.di.uminho.pt/pub/ctan/fonts/
User-Agent: lwp-request/6.00 libwww-perl/6.02

200 OK
Server: --------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
Content-Length: 32208
Content-Type: text/ftp-dir-listing
Client-Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2011 21:32:45 GMT
Client-Request-Num: 1

drwxr-xr-x  257 500      50          20480 May 30 06:27 .
drwxrwsr-x   18 500      50           4096 Jun  6 20:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 500      500          4096 Apr  7 19:13 Asana-Math
-rw-r--r--    1 500      500        573482 Apr  7 19:14 Asana-Math.zip
drwxr-xr-x    2 500      50           4096 May 20  2005 CJK
-r--r--r--    1 500      500      20384230 May 20  2005 CJK.zip
drwxr-xr-x    2 500      50           4096 May 20  2005 DayRoman
-r--r--r--    1 500      500        573352 May 20  2005 DayRoman.zip
drwxr-xr-x    2 500      50           4096 Sep  7  2007 LuxiMono
-r--r--r--    1 500      500        199660 May  6  2005 LuxiMono.zip
lrwxrwxrwx    1 500      50              8 Oct 14  2005 MnSymbol -> mnsymbol
lrwxrwxrwx    1 500      50             12 Oct 14  2005 Mnsymbol.zip -> mnsymbol.zip
```

---

```
['Asana-Math',     'd',              undef,    1302196380, 16877],
['Asana-Math.zip', 'f',              573482,   1302196440, 33188],
['CJK',            'd',              undef,    1116540000, 16877],
['CJK.zip',        'f',              20384230, 1116540000, 33060],
['DayRoman',       'd',              undef,    1116540000, 16877],
['DayRoman.zip',   'f',              573352,   1116540000, 33060],
['LuxiMono',       'd',              undef,    1189116000, 16877],
['LuxiMono.zip',   'f',              199660,   1115330400, 33060],
['MnSymbol',       'l mnsymbol',     8,        1129240800, 41471],
['Mnsymbol.zip',   'l mnsymbol.zip', 12,       1129240800, 41471],
```

Comment: +1 and thank you. I do have a question though. What is `GET -USe ftp://ftp.di.uminho.pt/pub/ctan/fonts/`? A shell command, or a perl command?

Comment: also could you please elaborate a bit on how to use `File::Listing` here? I do not see a convenient way of doing this. Comparing with regular expressions, I think `File::Listing` is harder to use. Thank you.

Comment: If you think that regex are easier than this, then do it yourself: `use LWP::Simple qw(get); use File::Listing qw(parse_dir); parse_dir get 'ftp://ftp.di.uminho.pt/pub/ctan/fonts/'; # returns array of arrayrefs as show above`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`Net::FTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::FTP) instead:

```
use Net::FTP;

$ftp = Net::FTP->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0)
  or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";

$ftp->cwd("/pub")
  or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->get("that.file")
  or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will **internally** generate an HTML document when you are viewing an FTP directory. The FTP server won't provide one.

If you want one, then you will have to iterate over the files and directories and generate your own.

Comment: The question is predicated on a false premise, this is how you go about getting as close to what was requested as possible.